# How to add multiple elements to a nav menu with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created my nav menu with this code, but it is missing a li tag. It only includes the `<ul><a>Menu 1</ul></a>` but I want it to have an li tag, so `<ul><li><a>Section 1</ul></li></a>`

This is what my code currently looks like

```
<ul id="navbar__list">
<a class="menu-items" id="menu-1" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
<a class="menu-items" id="menu-2" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
<a class="menu-items" id="menu-3" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
<a class="menu-items" id="menu-4" href="#section4">Section 4</a>
</ul>
```

Here is my current code I used to create the nav. I'm not sure how to add an additional li tag with this method, or do I need to do something else

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

//Build the nav
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);
});
```

This is what the HTML looks like and I have 4 sections. Here is section 1

```
<header class="page__header">
      <nav class="navbar__menu">
        <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
        <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <header class="main__hero">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
      </header>
      <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="active">
        <div class="landing__container">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
```

Comment: You'll be better off by using frameworks like foundation or bootstrap for achieving the same. If you would like to still create a custom menu, it'll be better to go with front-end frameworks like react or vue. Even if learning, it still pays to learn the right thing first. There's no reason to do this in plain javascript unless you're building your own framework. (Posting as a comment as it was posted as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

You would create the `li` in the same way that you create the `a`, by using `createElement()`.

Append the `a` to the newly created `li`.

Then, append the `li` to the `ul`.

```js
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

//Build the nav
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  
  // Create a list item
  const li = document.createElement("li")
  // Append the anchor to the list item
  li.appendChild(el);
  
  // Append the list item to the list
  navList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar__menu">
  <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
</nav>
```